# How to make whole row expanded?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting below overflow error and I want to make an expanded view for hashtags.

For example, **I want 4th hashtag in the new line**.

Ive tried to wrap `Row` with `Expanded` and tried to give `fix width` but not working.

**My issue** : [image]

**My code**:

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorRes.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: ColorRes.primaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(60),
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "PS",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: ColorRes.white,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Jane Mosca Battello",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Stage : ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: ColorRes.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: ColorRes.green,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Lead",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: ColorRes.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Source : ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: ColorRes.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: ColorRes.primaryColor,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Website",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: ColorRes.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: ["Buyer Lead", "Seller Lead","Buyer Lead ", "Seller Lead"]
                        .map(
                          (e) => Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorRes.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.7),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                            child: Text(
                              "#$e",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: ColorRes.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of row use Wrap Widget. it will work

Comment: it will make all child fit and will not move to overflowed child into next line

Comment: then instead of Row take list view and give scroll to horizontal. it will work

Comment: Can you code once? see the result which I want.

Comment: sorry, for given wrong output. i find the solution. you have to use Wrap instead of Row. Wrap widget will automatically send new widget to new line if it is overloading

Comment: Fixed with `Wrap` widget.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Output look like this]
Add your container to flexible widget

```
Row(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      "Buyer Lead",
       "Seller Lead",
       "Buyer Lead ",
       "Seller Lead",
       "Seller Lead",
       "Seller Lead",
      ]
      .map(
        (e) => Flexible(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
          child: Text(
          "#$e",
          style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.white,
         ),
     ),
   ),
  ),
 )
 .toList(),
)
```

Comment: Not working, Please take my code and try to run it into your system.